# How to implement this functionality in react?

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend

I want to make webzine website by React.
I want to implement that box size up and hided menu bar appears if I click index button as same as below figures.

[image]

[image]

what react library could help me to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There are many front-end libraries for React. By using these you can easily achieve this I'll recommend [Chakra UI](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/menu/usage) they have every good example on their website give it try.

> To Get Started with `Chakra UI` run `npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react @emotion/styled framer-motion` or follow their docs [here](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started)

**Code Example:-**

```
<Menu>
<MenuButton as={Button} rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />}>
  Index Button
 </MenuButton>
  <MenuList>
  {/* Menu Options */}
  <MenuItem>Download</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>Create a Copy</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>Mark as Draft</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem>Delete</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>Attend a Workshop</MenuItem>
</MenuList>
```